# Registering application in windows registry

Tags: windows, registry

Windows has a vague and ambiguous way of declaring standards for registering applications in the windows registry.

Following the official documentation for [application registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx) Microsoft recommends registering apps under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe
```

This recommendation however doesn't seem to be followed by developers since this key has not even been created on my system yet while other applications being registered into

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyApp
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\MyApp.exe
```

Each of the keys above has a different structure and thus different options (i.e. the key `SupportedTypes` being available in one but not the other).

What is the difference between registering apps under these different keys and in what scenarios would you chose one over another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there are multiple places in the registry where you can put application information and which key to use depends on what/why you are registering.

I would argue that the main registration point is the registration for "Default Programs" under [`SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#RegisteredApplications). If your application fits one of the [client types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144109(v=vs.85).aspx#_com_reg_elements) then you should point your RegisteredApplications value to `Software\Clients\%ClientType%\%YourCanonicalName%\Capabilities`, otherwise you can use any key like `Software\%YourCompany%\%YourApp%\Capabilities` or `Software\Classes\Applications\%Filename%\Capabilities`.

If you want your application to appear in the ["Open With" dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127445(v=vs.85).aspx) of a specific file extension then you can list your [ProgId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152(v=vs.85).aspx) under `HKCR\%.ext%\OpenWithProgids` or the application filename under `HKCR\%.ext%\OpenWithList`.

General "Open With" information is stored under [`HKCR\Applications\%Filename%`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#applications).

The [`Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#appPaths) key is mainly used as a %Path% environment variable extension for the shell so it can find the full path to your executable if the user types just the filename in the Run dialog. It can also contain some information about how your application handles "drag & drop" and URL protocols.

There is also some application info under `HKCR\AppID` but this is not applicable unless you have a COM server.

---

As far as you specific question goes, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\MyApp.exe` are documented registrations keys I already covered. The SupportedTypes key is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#applications).

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyApp` looks like a ProgId and those are generally used to [register file types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148(v=vs.85).aspx#fa_register_type) and [URL protocol handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).